# Change SSRS Report Server Instance Name

Tags: reporting-services

I am setting up SSRS on a windows 2019 server with SQL Server 2019 installed.  Once SSRS is installed and it prompts for first configuration is there anyway to change the default value of Report server Instance of "SSRS" to a different value?  See image.  I have tried a few things like amending  tag in the rsreportserver.config and tried changing the name of the install folder C:<install path>\SSRS but it is locked by a process and I tried stopping all SQL Server services etc but that did not work.

[image: Image of default instance name]

Can this default instance name be changed?